# A property of union closed families

Tags: combinatorics

Some tests gave me the impression that the following statement is right :

If a union closed family of sets ("union closed" means that the union of two sets from the family is always a member of the family) has at least ${k \choose r} + 1$ members with cardinality $r$, then this family has at least two members with cardinality $\geq k$.

Could anybody indicate a proof or literature ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the following: Let $A$ be a finite set with $k$ elements, then the number of subsets of $A$ with cardinality exactly $r$ is $\binom{k}{r}$.  Now, let $B$ be the union of the $\binom{k}{r}+1$ sets with cardinality $r$.  By above, the cardinality of $B$ is at least $k+1$.

Comment: OK, I used this fact in my tests, but is the statement an immediate consequence of this fact ?

Comment: I think I found a proof. I spoke of this question on Mathoverflow, so please go there (thread "Literature about a property of union closed families?") if you want to read more about it.